# Separate the text from the media in a Wordpress page

Tags: wordpress

I am making my first steps learning to code, so I decided to make a wordpress theme to continue learning from the practice.

I downloaded and installed wordpress locally and I made a Child Theme. I am setting up a menu to start making my portfolio website.

I know that I can create pages and subpages that is great. But now I would like to know if it's possible separate the text from the media in a page. The thing is that in the same page I would ike to have a picture slideshow and a link to read a description.

That is something possible to make in a page? or I need to make two pages ( one for the slideshow and one for the description)? I ask because in the page editor I can only see one form to put the images and the description all together so I don't know if that gives me possibilities to change the layout.

Do you have some suggestion? I would like to know if its possible so I would know if its worth to continue experimenting to achieve it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? You just want to display images, next to text?

Comment: I would like to have in the same page an image slide show and a button to switch between the text description and the image slideshow.

Comment: Sounds more like a jQuery/javascript job rather than something to do directly through WordPress

Comment: Ok. So I can make a single page and the I can focus in learning javascript an jquery to make it in that single page?

Comment: Of course you can. You'd probably be better off running it locally as just a HTML file to make edits easier, then putting it on WordPress after. At the end of the day - WordPress is just a content management system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your best to look at the some slideshow plugins that use shortcodes. Then just paste the shortcode on the page where you want the slideshow to be.

If you get lost go here swiftgrid.net and hit the green button I can help.

Mathew